# How to convert Haxe Array/Vector to another type

Tags: haxe

Let's say I've got an array or vector of some parent type. To pass it to a function, I need it to be some child type (which I know beforehand that all elements are guaranteed to be all that child type). Is there a convenient way to do that?  Right now I can only think to make a whole new array.

Also, it looks like it won't let me do it the other way around: it won't accept an array of child type in the place of the parent type.  Is there a good way to solve this situation as well?

It looks like `cast v` works, but is this the preferred way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> To pass it to a function, I need it to be some child type (which I know beforehand that all elements are guaranteed to be all that child type).

If you really are confident that that's the case, it is safe to use a `cast`. I don't think there's any prettier way of doing this, *nor should there be*, as it inherently isn't pretty. Having to do this often indicates a design flaw in your code or the API that is being used.

---

For the reverse case, it's helpful to understand *why* it's not safe. The reason is not necessarily as intuitive because of this thought process:

> *I can assign `Child` to `Base`, so why can't I assign `Array<Child>` to `Array<Base>`*?

This exact example is used to explain **Variance** [in the Haxe Manual](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-variance.html). You should definitely read it in full, but I'll give a quick summary here:

```haxe
var children = [new Child()];
var bases:Array<Base> = cast children;
bases.push(new OtherChild());

children[1].childMethod(); // runtime crash
```

If you could assign the `Array<Child>` to an `Array<Base>`, **you could then `push()` types that are incompatible with `Child` into it**. But again, as you mentioned, you can just `cast` it to silence the compiler as in the code snippet above.

*However*, this is not always safe - there might still be code holding a reference to that original `Array<Child>`, which now suddenly contains things that it doesn't expect! This means we could do something like calling `childMethod()` on an object that doesn't have that method, and cause a runtime crash.

The opposite is also true, if there's no code holding onto such a reference (or if the references are read-only, for instance via [`haxe.ds.ReadOnlyArray`](https://api.haxe.org/v/development/haxe/ds/ReadOnlyArray.html?)), it is safe to use a `cast`.

---

At the end of the day it's a trade-off between the performance cost of making a copy (which might be negligible depending on the size) and how confident you are that you're smarter than the compiler / know about all references that exist.